# Coverage Band Details in GeoServer Image Mosaic

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff

I want to publish an Image Mosaic layer with several images and I start with one image/granule. However, I find that the Coverage Band Details of this layer can not be recognized when I published this image.
[image]

I then try to load this image on ArcGIS. And the Coverage Band Details can be seen as well after I use ArcGIS to export the image to a new geotiff.

[image]

Does anyone know where GeoServer get these information? I checked the properties of both geotiffs in ArcGIS and find nothing different.

Software version:
GeoServer 2.23.0,
ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.

I use python and gdal to check both file and here is the result

```
print('Original Image===========')
ds = gdal.Open('original.tif')
metadata = ds.GetMetadata()
print(metadata)
print('Image Exported by ArcGIS===========')
ds = None
ds = gdal.Open('exported_by_arcgis.tif')
metadata = ds.GetMetadata()
```

The results are as follows:

```
Original Image===========
{'AREA_OR_POINT': 'Area', 'TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE': 'UltraMap Aerial v5.3.0.1 (Build 35.1.2107.501)'}
Image Exported by ArcGIS===========
{'AREA_OR_POINT': 'Area', 'DataType': 'Generic'}
```

Attributes in ArcGIS are as follows.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add gdalinfo output for the before and after images

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's strange that I can only get a few of the iteams using python and gdal GetMetadata.

Answer (score 2):

Typically image formats do not have an actual "band name", the names are based on heuristics like the color model of the image and the format involved.

So you are likely to get different results based on the format you're using, how it's configured, and the like.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The strange thing is that I can not find what differences in the two geotiffs cause the different recognition results in GeoServer. T_T –